# Facebook Logged in in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am building an IOS app. I am using storyboards to build the screens and I have integrated Facebook in my project.
I’m facing a problem that is in my app, if the user logged in through Facebook and closed the app, he has to logg in again but, I want the logged in to happen only once to enter into the app.

Here is my code:

```
(IBAction)fbLogin:(id)sender {





[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown"]

                                   allowLoginUI:YES

                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {



                                  switch (state) {

                                      case FBSessionStateOpen:

                                          [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {



                                              if (error) {



                                                  NSLog(@"error:%@",error);





                                              }

                                              else

                                              {

                                                  // retrive user's details at here as shown below





                                                  [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBuser, NSError *error) {

                                                      if (error) {

                                                          // Handle error

                                                      }



                                                      else {

                                                          NSString *userName = [FBuser name];

                                                          NSLog(@"username===%@",userName);

                                                           NSLog(@"sesseion=%@",session);

                                                                                                                    }

                                                  }];



                                                  NSLog(@"FB user first name:%@",user.first_name);

                                                  userName=user.first_name;

                                                  NSLog(@"FB user last name:%@",user.last_name);

                                                  NSLog(@"FB user birthday:%@",user.birthday);

                                                  NSLog(@"FB user location:%@",user.location);

                                                  NSLog(@"FB user username:%@",user.username);

                                                  NSLog(@"FB user gender:%@",[user objectForKey:@"gender"]);

                                                  NSLog(@"email id:%@",[user objectForKey:@"email"]);

                                                  NSLog(@"location:%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Location: %@\n\n",

                                                                         user.location[@"name"]]);

                                                  userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [user objectID]];

         }];

                                          break;





                                  }



                              } ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of allowLoginUI should be NO if there's a cached session (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2)

```
BOOL allowLoginUI = FBSession.activeSession.state != FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded;
```